# Remove hidden text from Range.Text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using VBA to process text in the first column of a Word document table.  The cell may have hidden text and I do not want it to be present in during processing.

```
Dim info as String
For Each oTable In doc.Tables
    For Each oRow In oTable.Rows
        info = oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text
        infoClean = RemoveHiddenText (info) ' is there such a beast ?
    Next
Next
```

What VBA would have to be in the RemoveHiddenText () function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
If oRow.Cells(1).Range.Font.Hidden Then
   oRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = ""
End If
```

I don't know what do you exactly mean by hidden text, but I think this is what you are looking for.